# What is a clean way of passing a list of ints between stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, csv, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which results in a temporary table populated with INTs. I also have another stored procedure which I want to take in a list of INTs to perform processing on them.

As far as I know there isn't a clean way to pass a list of values between stored procedures, so I converted the INTs inside my temporary table into a `VARCHAR` containing the INTs in CSV format. My other stored procedure then takes in the a `VARCHAR` containing the CSV values and parses them back into table format to begin processing.

My concern is my CSV method makes use of the `.Split` method, which I cannot use in my deployment environment and also seems a resource heavy way for passing values.

My table to CSV conversion in my first stored procedure looks like the following:

```
DECLARE @tmpCSV VARCHAR(250)
set @tmpCSV = '';
SELECT @tmpCSV = @tmpCSV + CAST(i.HistoryID AS VARCHAR) + ', ' FROM @tmpIntTbl i
```

My CSV to table conversion in my other stored procedure looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT CAST(items AS INT)
    FROM dbo.Split(@PassedInInts, ',')
```

Second SPROC definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SecondSPROC]
    (
        @TheIDS THENEWTYPE READONLY
    )
```

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to pass a list of INTs between stored procedures?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked into [table-valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) for this purpose? They are available from SQL Server 2008, I believe.

I imagine that you could create your list of `INT` values as a `@TABLE` variable, which you could then pass on to a second SP without too many problems.

If you need to perform any DML statements like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on the values, you could throw them into a new Table Variable inside the second SP for those purposes.

Doing this could save you the use of the `dbo.Split()` function you're using, as well as remove the need to create the actual temporary tables and perform the resultant cleanup afterwards.

A simple example might look like this:

```
CREATE TYPE TVPType AS TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT);

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TVPTest @TABLE TVPType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM @TABLE
    ;
END
;

DECLARE @TABLE AS TVPType;

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1,2,3);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (4,5,6);
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (7,8,9);

EXEC dbo.TVPTest @TABLE;
```

Returns:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
1     2     3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer 3BK. 
I have tried using table-valued parameters but when I try passing the table into my other stored procedure I get an error saying "Must declare the scalar variable". I'd imagine this could be solved via GO statements but SQL is very foreign to me and seems to throw errors under my other variables when I put GO in under my DECLAREs. 
In addition to this the creation of the second Stored Procedure is done in a different file, so it can't find the TYPE I created. Unfortunately I cannot just move the stored procedure to be created in the first SPROC either.

Comment: Hey Mark.  Can you maybe add your SP definitions to your question so that I can see where the problem is? You shouldn't be getting that error, granted that you're using the right version of SQL Server and declaring the types as needed.  Any extra info you could provide would allow me to sharpen my answer to your needs. Thanks.

Comment: It's a lengthy SPROC so I'm trying to avoid posting it in the question. The jist of it is I create the TYPE before my stored procedure and put a GO afterwards following my other questions recommendation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408027/cannot-pass-temporary-table-from-one-stored-procedure-to-another-with-error-mus/42408233#42408233) which is good as there is not scalar variable issue on other non-type variables up until I try to pass the TYPE variable into the other function, where it says the scalar error. I have put my definition for the second function in the question.

Comment: How about adding a screenshot of just the uppermost portion of the SP? We don't need the entire thing, but just seeing a screenshot of the queries you're trying to run might give me a clue as to why you're getting this error.  It's very difficult to debug it for you like this...

Comment: AFAIK, Table valued parameters are available since 2008 version